# Can I use two for loops on one function or is there a better way?

Tags: go

I am writing out a homework problem which I may have over-engineered with too many structs. It made sense at the time. I want to loop through Seasonal Discounts (through 2 different arrays- HighPrices, and LowPrices ) and just not sure if a) the set up is good or not, b) how to add the price in a less redundant manner.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println(getPrice(2, "bananas"))
}

func getPrice(p float32, f string) float32 {

    type HighPriceItems struct {
        items []string
        price float32
    }
    type LowPriceItems struct {
        items []string
        price float32
    }
    type seasonMatrix struct {
        h HighPriceItems
        l LowPriceItems
    }
    var seasonPrices = func() seasonMatrix {
        var h = HighPriceItems{}
        var l = LowPriceItems{}

        var season = seasonMatrix{}

        switch time.Now().Month() {

        case time.March, time.April, time.May, time.June, time.July:

            h := append(h.items, "apples", "oranges", "pears")
            l := append(l.items, "bananas", "grapes")
            season.h.items = h
            season.h.price = 4
            season.l.items = l
            season.l.price = 2
            return season
        case time.August, time.September, time.October, time.November, time.December, time.January, time.February:

            h := append(h.items, "bananas", "grapes")
            l := append(l.items, "apples", "oranges", "pears")
            season.h.items = h
            season.h.price = 4
            season.l.price = 2
            season.l.items = l
            return season
        }
        return season
    }

    const normalDiscount float32 = .75

    var x = p * normalDiscount
    var specials = seasonPrices()
    var finalPrice float32

    for _, n := range specials.h.items {

        if f == n {
            if specials.h.price > x {
                finalPrice = specials.h.price

            } else {
                finalPrice = x
            }
        }
    }
    for _, n := range specials.l.items {
        if f == n {
            if specials.l.price > x {
                finalPrice = specials.l.price
            } else {
                finalPrice = x
            }
        }
    }
    return finalPrice
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no reason for `HighPriceItem` and `LowPriceItem` types.

If you make it a single `PriceItems`, you'll be able to turn the 2 for loops at the end into a function over `PriceItems` and get rid of the duplicate code inside second for loop.

Also in Go `var specials = seasonPrices()` is typically written as `specials := seasonPrices()`